# CSRF Implementation

Tags: attacks, csrf, attack-vector

I am working on website,where I want include csrf checks by using referrer checks,will this be sufficient way to protect the form from csrf attack?

if not what an attacker can do to bypass it?

Comment: How will you handle browser configured to NOT send any referrer information (privacy plugins, etc.)? If you accept their requests, then you make a hole in your security. If you block them, then you deny access to your service to a whole range of users.

Answer (score 4):

According to OWASP:

> Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header on your own browser, it is impossible to do so in a CSRF attack. Checking the referer is a commonly used method of preventing CSRF on embedded network devices because it does not require a per-user state. This makes a referer a useful method of CSRF prevention when memory is scarce.

However

> However, checking the referer is considered to be a weaker from of CSRF protection. For example, open redirect vulnerabilities can be used to exploit GET-based requests that are protected with a referer check and some organizations or browser tools remove referrer headers as a form of data protection. There are also common implementation mistakes with referer checks. For example if the CSRF attack originates from an HTTPS domain then the referer will be omitted.

The complete explanation: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header

Answer (score 1):

I think that the way to solve it is to use Anti-CSRF Tokens and not to relay on referrer header. There are different implementations that can give Anti-CSRF Tokens out of the box, so you don't have to write it yourself.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Anti_CSRF_Tokens_ASP.NET